# Adding Back button to UINavigationController inside UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

The `UITabBarController` is loaded as a `rootViewController` from a `UINavigationController`. I have 6 `Tabs` and `FifthViewController` and `SixthViewController` comes under `More` tab and they push a `DetailsViewController` to show details. I am unable to show back button in `DetailsViewController` to go back to ParentViewController. I tried all the below options but, none of them is working.

I am loading `UITabBarController` as a initial view controller from `Storyboard` and have `FifthViewController` and `SixthViewController` as well from `Storyboard`. In `FifthViewController` I am setting Header

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.title = @"Alerts" ;
    self.tabBarController.title = @"Alerts" ;
}
```

In `DetailsViewController` I am setting Header

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //I tired all the below options to show back button
}

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] ;

self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] ;

self.tabBarController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] ;

self.tabBarController.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] ;
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show more code; not all of it, but just enough to see what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description you have it setup incorrectly.

The `UITabBarController` should be the app's `rootViewController`. Each tab should be a `UINavigationController`. Each navigation controller should be setup with the appropriate root view controller for each tab.

The tab bar controller itself should not be in a navigation controller.

You should not be setting the `backBarButtonItem` of any navigation item.

With the setup I describe, each tab has its own unique navigation. A user can be on tab two, for example, and move forward to the next view controller in that tab. And the tabs will remain visible. Now the user can go to any tab and later return to tab two and still be on the 2nd view controller for that tab.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am changing the flow. But both `FirstTabBarController` and `SecondTabBarController` are loading from More tab. I think they should already have a navigation controller. right?

Comment: Why do you have more than one tab bar controller?

Comment: To simplify the question I mentioned i have only two tabs. I have 6 tabs totally, and I need navigation controller for last two tabs which are in more tab. and I have only one tabbarcontroller

Comment: But your question states you have two tab bar controllers. Or perhaps those are just confusingly named view controllers. The fact that the tabs are in the "More" tab is irrelevant. The user might reorder the tabs or you might get 7 tabs on an iPad. Use a navigation controller for each tab that needs one.

Comment: Now it looks like you have six tab bar controllers. You really need to rename those view controllers. Example - name "FifthViewController" instead of "FifthTabBarController". The latter name implies the controller is a tab bar controller while the former implies the controller is a view controller (which it is).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98143/discussion-between-krish-and-rmaddy).

Answer (score 1):

You need a `UINavigationController` as the *child* of the `UITabBarController`, if you want it to function within the tab with a navigation stack and back button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am changing the flow. But both `FirstTabBarController` and `SecondTabBarController` are loading from More tab. I think they should already have a navigation controller. right?

Comment: Nothing has a Nav controller unless you've added it, directly before the view you want to be the root within that tab.